# dynamically create input elements based on clicked element

Tags: jquery, html, django

My question title isn't the best one, but here is the deal:

I have six paragraphs. Three of them contain text, and other three contain links, like this:

```
<p>Text 1</><p>Link one</>
<p>Text 2</><p>Link two</>
<p>Text 3</><p>Link three</>
```

Every link calls a jQuery function which should create an HTML input element instead of text in corresponding paragraph (eg: clicking Link three should create text input element in paragraph which contains Text 3).

On second click, the same link should create an AJAX call with some parameters, which my Django view will pick up, and act accordingly.

Currently, I have this:

```
$('.column a').click(function ()
{
    oldValue = $('#email').text()
    $('#email').html('<input type="text" value="'+oldValue+'"/>')
    $('a#changeMail').removeClass('button').addClass('success button')
});
```

and it works for one paragraph pair. How can I make it work for any "paragraph pair"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out jEditable.  I'm not totally sure what you're looking for but it is very customizable. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that structure this should work (heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uBZRW/2/)

```
$('.column a').click(function ()
{
    var targetParaphaph = $(this).parent().prev(); // This gets the previous <p>
    var value = targetParaphaph.text();
    targetParaphaph.html("<input type='text' value='"+value+"'/>");
    $(this).addClass('success'); // this results in "button success" class
});
```

Edit: I edited the original answer with multiple fixes to the code, fiddle contains a working example, if your structure is different you can implement a similar logic using jquery .parent(), .parents([selector]), .next(), .prev(), etc

jQuery DOM Traversing: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Thank you, it works. My amateurism made me forget to mention those paragraphs are in different divs. I'll edit the question with the real code, from my page. +1 for you either way.

Comment: Check the DOM traversing link, you should find all you need to know to adapt the logic to your code